# inter thread communicating using notify

Tags: java

I am try to run a code written in the book "JAVA 2 by Herbert Schildt".Here is the code

```
class Q 
{
    int n;
    boolean valueSet = false;

    synchronized int get() {
        if(!valueSet) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Got: " + n);

        valueSet=false;
        notify();

        return n;
    }

    synchronized void put(int n) {
        System.out.println("Put method called");

        if(valueSet) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Put method if check called");
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }

            this.n=n;
            valueSet=true;

            System.out.println("Put: " + n);

            notify();
        }
    }
}


class Producer implements Runnable {
    Q q;
    Producer(Q q) {
        this.q=q;
        new Thread(this,"Producer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int i=0;

        while(true) {
            q.put(i++);
        }
    }
}


class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Q q;

    Consumer(Q q) {
        this.q=q;
        new Thread(this,"Consumer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            q.get();
        }
    }
}

class PcFixed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main thread started");
        Q obj = new Q();
        new Producer(obj);
        new Consumer(obj);
    }
}
```

Output it is supposed to give is

> Put:1
>
> Got:1
>
> Put:2
>
> Got:2
>
> Put:3
>
> Got:3
>
> Put:4
>
> Got:4
>
> Put:5
>
> Got:5

But my problem is that when the thread is started in the `Producer` constructor it calls `run()` which  in turn goes into the `while` loop which calls `q.put()`. But it keeps executing the first statement of `put()` again and again (infinite loop). Why is it doing so ?

Comment: I dont see hundred's of blanks and this code is very readable . Sorry its not upto your standard and your answer is what is needed not rubbish .

Comment: Should really have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html for code convetions.

Comment: this is not the code style that i use . i dont know how to indent here for stack over flow so i just use one line gap between statements other wise i indent the code quite well .still i am in a learning process like everyone .

Comment: i know how to indent but when i copy and paste my indented code here , the indentations goes away and it takes a lot of time to indent again so i just post it giving one line gap between the statements .by the way it is quite in constructive to say that because my main purpose is to learn and solve my problem .You should rather focus on answering the question rather than pointing out not needed suggestions .If you care so much why not suggest an edit ?

Comment: -1 for attitude. SO is meant as a Q&A site for other people to look up existing questions and answers and so it matters if a question is not well formatted even if you don't care. Please try to format it yourself, it takes us time too.

Comment: its not only meant for others to look up ,it is also meant for people who have questions to ask .Yeah the attitude wasnt right ,i agree with that ,neither was their's.I think it is a waste of my time to learn how to indent on this site .This forum should automatically indent codes that are not indented so that it saves time for the poster and obviously the reader .

Comment: You're the one wanting free help, and I don't see why your time is so much more valuable than mine if you're not paying me. Even if automatic indentation were a good idea (it's not), the blank lines would still have been an issue.

Comment: How about "Auto blank line omit check"?.
And I am sorry for that bad attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valueSet is never set to true, because the only assignment of true is within an if (valueSet) { ... } block.

You need to move the this.n = n and subsequent lines out of the if (valueSet) { ... } block.

BTW, although understanding this stuff has its uses, using the higher-level concurrency classes in java.util.concurrent (such as a blocking queue) is usually a better way to go these days.

Comment: This code is from a book not mine .and this not running as it is supposed to be,read my question again

Comment: valueSet is being set to true in the put method of Q class ,see their and read carefully what i have asked in the question or try to run it on your compiler ,this is a very unique problem i am facing as it is going into an infinite loop which it isnt supposed to

Comment: The "valueSet = true;" assignment is within "if (valueSet) { ... }". Since valueSet is initialised to false, the body of the if statement is never entered, and valueSet never becomes true. put() then reduces to just its first line, hence you get your observed behaviour. You need to move the } from below the notify() to above the this.n=n statement.

Comment: done ,but it still showing problems.the value of "i" passed is showing  some problem.It is showing garbage i guess because it is supposed to show put 1 got 1 etc etc but it shows put 22973 got 22973 put 22974 got 22974 why so?